# How to add span tag in wysiwyg editor magento 2.3.x

Tags: magento2, custom, wysiwyg, editor

I just wanted to see is it possible to do add a custom text format as SPAN tag in Magento wysiwyg editor.
The current options we get is paragraph/ heading 1-6 I want to add span there.
Could anyone help me or give me some guide to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, if you put blank span then editor might remove your span.

```
<span>&nbsp;</span>
```

You can use like this.

Thank you
Hiren Patel

Comment: Is it possible to create a custom format option example what I mean is if we click the format option we get all options such as headings and paragraphs can I do something like. Create a custom Span tag?